# When creating an iOS live activity I get the error:

Tags: ios, activitykit

When creating an iOS live activity I get the error:
`The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.ActivityKit.ActivityInput error 0.).`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this problem. It is because of "Marge Codes". During marge codes someone deleted my Profile about pushNotification [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHBqq.png).

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you main app is opend push notification.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).